# Clearing contextual links'cache

Tags: 8, caching, navigation

I'm  listing nodes in a block view which is located in a [panel](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) managed by [page_manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager).

I need for these nodes somes custom opérations in contextual links, so i implmented [hook_contextual_links_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_contextual_links_alter/8.5.x)() to add some operations.

All works.

**Problem :** my custom contextual links are appearing in new nodes of this list (or modified nodes) but not in old ones. To make them appear, i need to flush my browser's cache (i'm also using [memcache](https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache)).
Editing all these nodes or clearing browser's cache are the only ways i currently found to get contextual links working for old nodes.

I need to achieve this during the update of my app with hook_update of my module without editing all these nodes or asking users to clear their cache.

*PS : i tryed to clear all cache with & without drush -individually or not-, by all ways, all modules are last stable version, drupal 8.5.2*

Comment: On the client you can't control the browser cache for content delivered in the past. On the server Drupal caches are cleared automatically when an update hook is executed, so you only need to define an update hook and if you don't have anything else to update you can leave it empty.

Comment: You are right, i was thinking storage was located somewhere in database/memcache (tempstore or something but i did not find anything...) that was a browser localStorage. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cache is located in sessionStorage on modern browsers.

[image: Session Storage]

I'm just clearing the entire sessionStorage with `window.sessionStorage.clear();` on logout to solve this problem. I could be more precise on this deletion, but it does not matter in this app.